# Pass variable inter threadgroups and samplers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

How to use output of first sampler in two sampler.

I want to two WebDriver Sampler tests in jmeter consecutively. I can current url after testing, but I can't use as a variable in second sampler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass variable between 2 Samplers in one Thread Group:

1. In first Sampler:

   ```
   WDS.vars.put('url', WDS.browser.getCurrentUrl())
   ```
2. In second Sampler:

   ```
   var urlFromSampler1 = WDS.vars.get('url')
   ```

   where `WDS.vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in the current thread scope

If you need to pass the variable between 2 samplers in different Thread Groups:

1. In first Sampler:

   ```
   WDS.props.put('url', WDS.browser.getCurrentUrl())
   ```
2. In second sampler:

   ```
   var urlFromSampler1 = WDS.props.get('url')
   ```

   where `WDS.props` is basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which are global across the whole JVM instance

References:

- [WebDriver Sampler: General Concepts](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/#General-concepts)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)